# Eclipse - Unable to view the Android Eclipse plugin

Tags: android, eclipse, adt

In Eclipse IDE I am trying to connect Android SDK to Eclipse.

1. I installed ADT plugin by,

*Help* - > *Install new Software* `https://dl-ssl.google.com/android/eclipse`

2. Then installed SDK by *Windows* - > *preferences* , Android SDK was also installed, but I don't see the "Android Application" in the menu as shown in screenshot. Also I don't see the "Android" option that should be available in the top right corner(as shown in the screenshot).

[image]

**My Questions**

1. Have I installed the ADT and configured Android SDK properly ?
2. Why am I unable to run the Android application ?

Please let me know if further details are needed.

Comment: Just as a heads up, Google's official way to develop is no longer with Eclipse. You should seriously consider migrating to Android Studio (http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/migrate.html)

Comment: Yup, support ended as of 2016 for Eclipse.

Comment: @jlindenbaum Yeah I know that Android Studio for my configuration is too slow So I am using eclipse. Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a run configuration, then there will be displayed this added configuration.

Edit:
After installing the Android plugin in eclipise I needed to reimport the project, then everything worked fine.

Comment: Ok But I dont see the "Android" in the top right corner ?(Top right corner in screenshot)

Comment: Well try this: [link] (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_eclipse.htm)

Comment: Did this know and worked completly fine, for Android Apps I suggest you to use if possible Android Studio or IntelliJ IDEA in future

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your Android SDK path in Windows -> Preferences yet? that should be first step.

If you have already done that, then goto Help -> Install New Software and click on Already installed link. Check whether you can see ADT installed in the list of installed packages?

Comment: Yes ADT is installed.

Comment: How about SDK path in preferences?